# In angularjs, how to copy one object into another?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking the way to extend one dynamic object with another.

Lets say we have two objects:

```
person = { 
    FirstName: "John", 
    LastName: "Doe", 
    IsStudent: false };

student = { 
    University: "MIT", 
    Faculty: "Computers", 
    IsStudent: true }
```

**Is it possible** to copy student object into person object so that I can get extended person object of this structure:

```
person = { 
    FirstName: "John", 
    LastName: "Doe", 
    University: "MIT", 
    Faculty: "Computers", 
    IsStudent: true };
```

Basically the idea is to update structure and state of person object to include student information from student object:

- person's properties that dont exist in student remain
- person's properties that exist in student are overwritten (like IsStudent property)
- student properties are added to person thus creating and extended version of person

Important: not to copy property-by-property manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for `extend`. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend).

```
angular.extend(student, person);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the funtionality you mentioned, you can do it in JS alone as well using ES6.

Here is the documentation for ES6 on [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let person = {
  FirstName: "John",
  LastName: "Doe",
  IsStudent: false
};

let student = {
  University: "MIT",
  Faculty: "Computers",
  IsStudent: true
};

console.log(Object.assign(person, student));
console.log(angular.extend(person, student));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```